# How should one handle AJAX success/error responses in Clojure re-frame?

Tags: clojure, re-frame

I love re-frame, but I realize that I'm having a bit of trouble finding a nice pattern for handling AJAX responses.

My situation is the following:

I have a "global" event handler that triggers some AJAX call and dispatches to some other global event handler, depending on whether that call was successful, e.g.:

```
(reg-event-db :store-value
  (fn [db [_ value]]
    (do-ajax-store value
                   :on-success #(dispatch [:store-value-success %])
                   :on-error   #(dispatch [:store-value-error %])
    db))

(reg-event-db :store-value-success
  (fn [db [_ result]]
    (assoc db :foobar result)))

(reg-event-db :store-value-error
  (fn [db [_ error]]
    (assoc db :foobar nil
              :last-error error)))
```

(I am aware of `reg-event-fx` and stuff, I'm just avoiding it here for the sake of brevity and because I think it does not make any difference for my problem).

I also have (multiple, distinct) UI components that might trigger the `:store-value` event, like so:

```
(defn button []
  (let [processing? (reagent/atom false)]
    (fn button-render []
      [:button {:class (when @processing? "processing")
                :on-click (fn []
                            (reset! processing? true)
                            (dispatch [:store-value 123]))}])))
```

So in this case the component has local state (`processing?`) that is supposed to depend on whether the AJAX call is still in progress or not.

Now, what is the proper pattern here to have the `button` component react to the events `:store-value-success` and `:store-value-error` in order to reset the `processing?` flag back to `false` after the AJAX call has finished?

Currently, I'm working around that problem by passing down callbacks but that seems really ugly because it clutters the event handlers' code with stuff that does not really belong there.

The best solution that I've thought of would be to have the `button` component being able to hook into the `:store-value-success` and `:store-value-error` events and install its own handler for those events, like this:

```
(defn button []
  (let [processing? (reagent/atom false)]
    (reg-event-db :store-value-success
      (fn [db _]
        (reset! processing? false)))
    (reg-event-db :store-value-error
      (fn [db _]
        (reset! processing? false)))
    (fn button-render []
      [:button {:class (when @processing? "processing")
                :on-click (fn []
                            (reset! processing? true)
                            (dispatch [:store-value 123]))}])))
```

However, that does not work. As it seems, re-frame does not allow multiple event handlers per event. Instead, a subsequent invocation of `reg-event-db` on one single event id will replace the previous event handler.

So how do you guys handle situations like this?

Comment: Also take a look at https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-http-fx

Comment: Thanks, I've been aware of that. However, I don't see how that solves the described problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, just wanted to bring it to your attention. :)

Comment: Ah, I see :) . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `reg-event-fx` ([src](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/docs/Effects.md#the-effects-map)) might indeed help solve your problem.

You could add a subscription that watches app-state e.g.

```
(rf/reg-sub
  :app-state
  (fn [db]
    (get db :app-state)))
```

and add this to your button, perhaps with a state function e.g.

```
(defn btn-state [state]
  (if (= state :processing)
     "processing"))
```

And then in the AJAX handler, you could add an fx to update the state-

```
(reg-event-fx              ;; -fx registration, not -db registration
  :ajax-success
  (fn [{:keys [db]} [_ result]]             
     {:db       (assoc db :app-state :default)         
     :dispatch [:store-value-success result]}))

 (reg-event-fx              ;; -fx registration, not -db registration
    :ajax-error
      (fn [{:keys [db]} [_ result]]             
         {:db       (assoc db :app-state :default)         
         :dispatch [:store-value-error result]}))
```

and update the AJAX handler

```
(reg-event-db :store-value
  (fn [db [_ value]]
    (do-ajax-store value
               :on-success #(dispatch [:ajax-success %])
               :on-error   #(dispatch [:ajax-error %])
    db))
```

This would be one way to handle it via -fx. I think you have already started to see the need for tracking app state, and I think bumping it up into the subscriptions would help with complexity, at which point your button render is greatly simplified.

```
 (defn button []
      [:button {:class (btn-state @app-state)
                :on-click (dispatch [:store-value 123]))}])))
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.

However, I think the code you provide is indeed cleaner than what I had.
Although I find it somewhat awkward to promote the button-local state to be global state. But maybe my idea of that state has just been incorrect, because it is not really button-local state, but indeed app-global state, because it's about an AJAX call going on, and not just about the button itself ;) .

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, I would recommend to use [http-fx](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-http-fx) and make `processing?` part of your global state. The code would look like this:

Events:

```
(reg-event-fx  
  :request 
  (fn [{:keys [db]} [_ method url data]]  
    {:http-xhrio {:method          method
                  :uri             url
                  :params          data
                  :format          (ajax/json-request-format) 
                  :response-format (ajax/json-response-format {:keywords? true})
                  :on-success      [:success-response method url]
                  :on-failure      [:error-response method url]}
     :db  (assoc db :processing? true)}))

(reg-event-db
  :success-response
  (fn [db [_ method url result]]
    (assoc db :foobar response
              :processing? false)}))

(reg-event-db
  :error
  (fn [db [_ method url result]]
    (assoc db :foobar nil 
              :last-error result
              :processing? false)}))
```

Subscriptions:

```
(reg-sub
  :processing
  (fn [db _]
    (:processing? db)))
```

View:

```
(defn button []
  (let [processing? @(rf/subscribe [:processing])]
    [:button {:class (when processing? "processing")
              :on-click #(dispatch [:store-value 123]))}])))
```

Hint: You could reuse this code with all your requests.